Пробую работу с горутинами, но вылезает дедлок
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"

    add "github.com/XRS0/gitHelper/internal/handlers/add"
    commit "github.com/XRS0/gitHelper/internal/handlers/commit"
)

func main() {
    Init()
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading data:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Commands executed: \n")
    cmds := strings.Split(text, " ")
    printCommands(cmds)
    rangeCommands(cmds)
}

func Init() {
    flag := "ɢɪᴛHᴇʟᴘᴇʀ"
    fmt.Println(flag)
}

func printCommands(commands []string) {
    if len(commands) == 0 {
        return
    }
    for _, word := range commands {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", word)
    }
}

func rangeCommands(commands []string) {
    if len(commands) == 0 {
        return
    }

    // var arrayFunc []func()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(commands))

    for _, word := range commands {
        switch word {
        case "commit":
            go commit.GitCommitWithMessage(&wg)
            // arrayFunc = append(arrayFunc, func() {
            //  commit.GitCommitWithMessage(&wg)
            // })
        case "add":
            go add.GitAdd(&wg)
            // arrayFunc = append(arrayFunc, func() {
            //  add.GitAdd(&wg)
            // })
        }
    }

    // for _, fn := range arrayFunc {
    //  go func(f func()) {
    //      f()
    //  }(fn)
    // }

    wg.Wait()
}

// file, err := os.Create("data.txt")
// reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
// input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
// _, err = file.WriteString(input)
// file, err := os.Create("data.txt")

// fmt.Printf("combined out:\n%s\n", string(out))
// out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()


func GitCommitWithMessage(wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Enter a commit name:\n")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Ошибка при чтении данных:", err)
    }
    fullCmd := fmt.Sprintf(`git commit -m "%s"`, text)
    cmd := exec.Command(fullCmd)
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
func GitAdd(wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Enter a commit name:\n")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cmd := exec.Command("git", "add", text)
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}



Deadlock обычно возникает из-за взаимоблокировки горутин.
Вызывать в горутине подобное reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin) очень плохая практика, os.Stdin является общим ресурсом и Вы из N горутин пытаетесь с ним взаимодействовать
